# Ruby on Rails production environment having SQL issues

Tags: linux, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm rather new to rails applications, and their respective deployment procedures. I've been having some issues with an application that I plan to run on my server, in the production environemt. The application, and rake, has no problem querying the production database **for** information, however a problem occurrs whenever the application, or rake, needs to modify the production database. All of my environments are on the same server, with the same user. The server is a correctly configured MySQL server. All modifications complete successfully with test, and development environments. This is what happens:

- Rake/Application successfully connects to production DB (verified with SQL logs)
- Rake/Application then successfully modifies the information (also verified)
- (Now the wierd stuff happens) rake/application then ROLLBACK's the information it wrote (also verified)
- If I were to have run rake I would then be told that the server refused my connection

I executed the same sequence of commands in the in the same order in the other two environments, and they all completed, and COMMIT'd successfully.

- The database configuration's entries are identical, save for the database name (*-dev, *-test, *).
- All databases exist
- All database permissions are identical
- All required tables exists in all three databases

Furthermore, I scucessfully connected to the production DB with gmysqlcc and executed the EXACT commands executed by the application, or rake, with the same credentials as the application/rake. The executed perfectly, and without flaw or complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by modifying casein's production-environment configuration.
Rails was rolling back the commit when casein encountered an error when attempting to mail me about updates.

This problem would have been spotted earlier - should casein have provided more detailed error messages.